# JQuery: Verify if in a collection of inputs (of type checkbox) one is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html

I have collection of inputs of type checkbox

```
var collection = $('.className');
console.log(collection);
```

result is:

```
[span.className, span.className, span.className]
```

how to check if there is at least one checked

Comment: And HTML code, how it is displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector, and then check the `length` property to see if any elements were matched:

```
if ($(".className:checked").length) {
    //At least 1 is checked!
}
```

However, your output looks like you have `span` elements, not `input` elements. If the checkboxes are descendants of the `.className` elements, add a space before the `:checked` selector.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('.className input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length>0){
   console.log("At least 1 selected!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test for *checked*: `$('.className:checked')`;

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.className input:checked').length > 0
```

I'm assuming your checkbox is inside a span since .className is giving you an array of spans.